# Using socket.io in modules and routes Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am having some issues using socket.io is modules. I have changed the way I do it quite drastically, however everything seems to be working, except being able to send userdata back to my socket connection:

Here is my io.js file: `/config/io`

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/

var io = require('socket.io')();
const moment = require('moment');

// Socket stuff
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('login', function (userdata) {
    socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
    socket.handshake.session.save();
    console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata);
  });

  // Server Time
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
      var momentNow = moment();
      var data = momentNow.format('LT');
      socket.emit('time', data);
    }, 60000);

  // Chat - Needs work
  socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    var username = 'Message'; //socket.handshake.session.userdata.username;
    var message = '[' + moment().format('LT') + '] ' + username + ': ' + msg;
    io.emit('message', message, username);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
      delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
      socket.handshake.session.save();
    }

    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

});

module.exports = io;
```

Here is where I'm trying to emit the data `/config/passport`: (please note that userdata does indeed contain the right information!)

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var io = require('./io');

module.exports = function(passport) {

  // Local Strategy login
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

    // Match Username
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    db.query(sql, [username], function(err, rows) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (!rows.length) {
        return done(null, false, {
          type: 'loginMessage',
          message: 'Wrong Login',
        });
      }

      //  Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        if (isMatch) {
          var userdata = rows[0];
          io.emit('login', userdata); // HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO EMIT IT
          // console.log(rows[0]);
          return done(null, rows[0]);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            type: 'loginMessage',
            message: 'Wrong Login',
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

Now here is my main app file: (leaving out a bunch of stuff)

```
var io = require('./config/io');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Init http server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Attach IO
io.attach(server);

// Listen
server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 8080...');
});
```

Now, everything seems to be working fine, except being able to emit the data. Now I tried logging it client side as well (just in case it was emitting on client-side and not server-side) but it is not doing that as well.

Comment: Okay, so I have looked at many of the same issues, and it seems this SHOULD work... but why doesn't it? It is emitting to the same instances (or trying to). All the resolved answers I can find to this problem, have done it the same way I have done it. I can't understand why it would work for them and not me? Everything else works, just not this.

Comment: When you `.emit()` on the server, the message goes to the client, not to the server.  When you `.emit()` on the client, the message goes to the server, not to the client.  That seems to be your fundamental misunderstanding here.  You appear to be doing `xx.emit("login")` on the server and then expecting `socket.on("login", ...)` on the server to see that message.  That isn't how socket.io works.  Normally, you would just call a function to execute some other code on the server - you wouldn't need to emit a message to yourself.

Comment: The issue is passport, io, and my main server are different files and I want the login function from passport to send over the data to socket.io. If I can't get that to happen then it hinders my game, due to i would have to do the for a lot of files. Also... It didn't work for client side either so... Either it is not working or I missed something.

Comment: That just sounds like you need to export and import the right functions so you can call a function in another module from within your passport code or choose to organize the code differently.  Sounds like regular module management stuff to allow you to call what you want from where you want.

Comment: Mmm if that were the case the io.on('connections') wouldn't have worked in passport. But thinking about it, the passport logic happens before the socket.io connection. So I now know why it didn't work like that. However I am curious how I emit to the socket out of the io function. Like is it io.sockets.emit? insead of io.emit.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  When you're doing auth with passport, the page hasn't even been served yet to the browser so there's no way, there's an active socket.io connection yet from that page.  Further, `io.on('connection', ...)` will see the next connection comes in, but it will also see ALL future connections and each time a new page goes into the passport code, you'll add yet another `io.on('connection;, ...)` handler.

Comment: So, your whole logic of even attempting to send to the socket is just wrong because there is no connected socket at that time.  Instead, you should probably just put something in the page session that you can use later WHEN the page later connects in your one global `io.on('connection, ...)` handler in the `io` module.

Comment: Oh no I've completely abandoned doing it from the passport thing. I no longer need to do it that way, nor want to anymore, I found an easier way that allows me to control it a tiny bit better. I am asking now once connected, how do I emit/on to a socket that's not inside the connection function. io.sockets.emit/on?

Comment: If you're in a handler for an Ajax call and you want to `.emit()` to the connection for the page that the ajax call is coming from, then you need to use something like [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) so you can get the current socket.io socket from the session object.  But, that only works for an ajax call, not for a page load because there is no connection yet for a page load.

Comment: It will have a connection. Assume everything is working as it should be. The player is connected to the socket.io server, I send a .emit from client side. How would I catch that outside my main io.js file. the module exports io. Would it be io.sockets? And to emit back to the client-side.

Comment: Sorry: io.sockets.emit() and io.sockets.on(). If I just did io.on() and io.emit it would do it for all clients, and I don't want that.

Comment: Another module can do its own `io.on('connection', ...)` and then do `socket.on()` inside that, but it needs to do it only once (not inside a request handler) and obviously you need to get the `io` object in the other module somehow for use with `io.on('connection', ...)`.  As far as I know, `io.sockets.on()` is not a thing.

Comment: Weird, I wonder why I've seen so many people do io.sockets then. Maybe its deprecated. And hmmm, I think I'll try that.So if I wanted to do `io.on('connection'...)` inside another module, I'd have to wrap `module.export = function()` inside of it, right? (I'm not 100% sure what qualifies as handlers yet). Anyways this will be my last question, cause this is far off topic... actually no that wouldn't work because this function would be inside of a router... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is an actual working answer. It s a work-around, and I completely abandoned trying to do it from the passport login handler itself. But here is how I did it:

IO code:

```
  var session = socket.handshake.session;
  socket.on('login', function () {
    if (socket.handshake.session.passport === undefined) {
      var destination = '/';
      socket.emit('not logged', destination);
    } else {
      console.log('user logged in');
      var userId = session.passport.user;
      var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';
      var query = db.query(sql, userId, function (err, rows) {
        session.userdata = rows[0];
        session.save();
        var dataObj = session.userdata;
        socket.emit('sart up', dataObj);
      });
    }
  });
```

And jQuery:

```
// Connection Successful
socket.on('connect', function () {
  connected = true;
  socket.emit('login');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  connected = false;
});

socket.on('not logged', function (destination) {
  window.location.href = destination;
});

socket.on('start up', function (dataObj) {
});
```

I'm not a huge fan of having to do it this way, I would have liked to handle everything sever-sided, but for now this is working, and will use until I figure out how to do it the way I'd like to.